# How this query works?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

So, i have a piece of code

```
var _activeContract = (from cnt in UnitOfWork.Context.Contract.Where(w => w.IS_DELETED == 0 && w.CONTRACT_STATUS_ID == (int)NemsKysContractStatusEnum.Aktif)
    join sei in UnitOfWork.Context.SiteExtendedInfoList.Where(w => w.IS_DELETED == 0) on cnt.SITE_ID equals sei.SITE_ID
    join sr in UnitOfWork.Context.Subregion.Where(w => w.IS_DELETED == 0) on sei.RN_SUBREGION_ID equals sr.ID
    join r in UnitOfWork.Context.Region.Where(w => w.IS_DELETED == 0) on sr.REGION_ID equals r.ID
    join mr in UnitOfWork.Context.MainRegion.Where(w => w.IS_DELETED == 0) on r.MAIN_REGION_ID equals mr.ID
    select new { MRNAME = mr.NAME, cnt.ID }).GroupBy(g => g.MRNAME).OrderBy(t => t.Key).Select(s => new { name = s.Key, data = s.Count() }).ToList();
```

I can't understand the last line.

As I know it says to create the output sequence, each element of it is
`{ MRNAME = mr.NAME, cnt.ID }` i.e. anon object. Then we group this sequence by `MRNAME` and then we order it by `Key` (part `OrderBy(t=>t.Key)`). What `Key`? Where is this key from? Because we just have two fields: `MRNAME` and `cntID`, don't we?

Then I can't understand how
`Select(s => new { name = s.Key, data = s.Count() })` works. It creates on each element of previous sequence of `{ MRNAME = mr.NAME, cnt.ID }` objects a new sequence each element of that is an object like `{ name = s.Key, data = s.Count() }`.

Again i don't understand what `Key` is here and what we count calculate field data by `s.Count()`, what we count exactly?

Comment: You *don't* need joins if you create relations and navigation properties in your context. It's the ORM's job to create the joins from the relations you defined. As it is, the entire query is very hard to understand and probably results in a very complex and slow SQL query

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you very much for your suggestion, i understand you right, but this code is not mine and i have no right to change it. So I still have a problem

Comment: As for the last line, it seems to be performing a `select` that isn't needed - the `GroupBy` itself is enough. Looks like this is an attempt to perform a `SELECT Name, count(*) ... GROUP BY Name ORDER BY Name`. You can do that with `.GroupBy(mr=>mr.Name).Select(g=>new {Neme=g.Key,Count=g.Count()}).OrderBy(t=>t.Name);`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, thank you for your help, i understand almost everything, but still don't understand what Key means here. What the field it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  from ...
  select new { MRNAME = mr.NAME, cnt.ID })  //1
.GroupBy(g => g.MRNAME)  //2
.OrderBy(t => t.Key)  //3
.Select(s => new { name = s.Key, data = s.Count() })  //4
.ToList();
```

Each element of the output from GroupBy is an IGrouping, which has a Key property.

Reading the code call by call:

```
//1 Each element has MRName and ID properties.
//2 Group the elements by the MRName property, we now have a query consisting of groups.
//3 Order the groups by the Key, which is the MRName property.
//4 Turn each group into a new element.  Each element has a name and data property.
```